# why does WGET return network is down?

Tags: wget

When I try to use wget to download the file from a remote server, it returns 'failed: Network is down' as below, what does it mean? does it mean the local network is down? or the remote server's network is down?

**Connecting to 192.168.0.1:8080... failed: Network is down.
Retrying.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Network is down` is the [strerror](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strerror.3.html) output for [`ENETDOWN`](http://www-numi.fnal.gov/offline_software/srt_public_context/WebDocs/Errors/unix_system_errors.html).

If you look at the manual page of - for example [connect](http://linux.die.net/man/3/connect), you can see that the reason for getting `ENETDOWN` is;

> ENETDOWN
>             The local network interface used to reach the destination is down.

In other words, it's normally caused by a *local* network problem.